# WordPress plugin options and jQuery

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, options

I'm creating a plugin that uses jQuery to modify some css, but what I can't figure out is how you can control the execution of the jQuery with WordPress plugin options (like checkboxes true/false). Can WordPress options be used as "variables" in jQuery? Or would every case require a unique .js file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable can be passed to jQuery or any javascript using `wp_localize_script`.

Example:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'prefix_enqueue_vars' );
function prefix_enqueue_vars() {
$script_vars = array(
      'setting_1' => get_option( 'some_option' ),
      'setting_2' => get_option( 'another_option' ),
);

wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script', 'path/to/script.js', array( 'jquery' ), true);
wp_localize_script( 'my_script', 'unique_name', $script_vars );

}
```

How to get the variables in your javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$var_1 = unique_name.setting_1
$var_2 = unique_name.setting_2

});
```

WordPress will output your variables between `<sript> </script>` tags before enqueuing the javascript file so they will be available to use.

See [wp_localize_script](http://ottopress.com/tag/wp_localize_script/) from Otto on WordPress for more information.

#### Edit:

Try adding the variables to a function that returns the value.  I'm using the exact code below and it works.

```
wp_localize_script( 'cmb-scripts', 'MaxChar', array( 'charlimit' => c3m_get_the_size( $excerpt_length[0] ) ) );
```

The function that returns the variables below:

```
function c3m_get_the_size() {
global $post; global $prefix;
$box_size = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $prefix.'box_size', true );
 if  ( $box_size == 'single-single' ) { $excerpt_length = 150; 
} elseif ( $box_size == 'single-double' ) { $excerpt_length = 150; 
} elseif ( $box_size == 'single-triple' ) { $excerpt_length = 150;

}
return $excerpt_length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the eye opener Chris_O, I can indeed see the extra script in the head section. However, the option value is not printed, I'm seeing something like `var unique_name = {setting_1: ""};`. I followed Otto's tut on the Settings API to create the options, and I think I set up everything correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Triple P There was a syntax error in the $script_vars array.  I edited the code above.  Give it another try.

Comment: Over at Otto's page a commenter recently wrote: "The output from the validator callback is totally masked, at least in WordPress 3.1.2. Echo, print_r, etc… None of them output anything. I have debug set to true in my wp_config and still nada." Could that be the reason why there is no output?

Comment: Try using a function to return the variables.  See Edit.

Comment: Adding `'foo' => 'bar'` to the array works fine, so I guess it has something to do with storing or retrieving the options. Is it ok that "bar" is outputted between double quotes? Thanks for your enlightening answer!